# Deadlock on table which is not involved in the queries

Tags: sql-server

I have the following graph:

[image]

Both Processes execute the same query, and it do not include the `IncidentCorrelations` table:

[image]

Thus, I don't understand why they want to lock IncidentCorrelations? The index (`IDX_IncidentCorrelations_Pair`) contains `Incidents` table reference. IncidentCorrelations has as FK with cascade delete on IncidentId. IncidentCorrelations is however empty.

My second question is what the object lock is?

Comment: Triggers? Cascading? Just because you don't reference the table in the query doesn't mean it isn't as a result of it.

Comment: The object name `dbo.IncidentCorrrelations` involved in the deadlock suggests its related to the `dbo.Incidents` table that's the delete target, likely with a foreign key constraint being checked in the query plan. Upload the plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. Index tuning (e.g. and index on the foreign key column) may help avoid the deadlock.